# Must I copy a block here?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I understand that you must copy blocks in order for them to stick around after a stack frame exits. But, how does that apply to stack-allocated blocks used within a nested block as in the following code example:

```
- doSomethingFunkyThenCall:(void(^)(int someValue))callback
{
    [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        // ... do some work here, potentially nesting into further blocks ...
        callback(result);
    }];
}
```

Obviously, the `doSomethingFunkyThenCall:` stack frame will terminate before the callback is executed, so it will have to be copied. But will this happen automatically in the call to `addOperationWithBlock:` or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should do a `callback = [[callback copy] autorelease];` at the top of this method.

Objects used in blocks are retained automatically, but sending a stack-block retain actually does nothing (because the semantics of retain require it to return the receiver), so will be gone once we leave the frame it was created in.

Sources:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html
http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#objcblocks

EDIT: It turns out I'm wrong. @bbum points out below that Block_copy will copy recursively, and since `addOperationWithBlock:` copies it's block, the callback is also copied.

Comment: Nope;  no need to copy the block in this case.  When the block enqueued with `addOperationWithBlock:` is copied (which `NSOperationQueue` will do), it will copy the encapsulated block.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW1

Comment: Thanks bbum and joerick! I hadn't seen this paragraph from that link before: "When you copy a block, any references to other blocks from within that block are copied if necessary—an entire tree may be copied (from the top). If you have block variables and you reference a block from within the block, that block will be copied."

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, it will happen automatically. Cocoa's design principles imply in general that you're not responsible for objects (their memory management, passing blocks [which are, in fact, implemented as proper Objective-C objects], etc.) you haven't created. So you can just pass down the block you received as a parameter, and the runtime will manage it as per its needs.